# How can I optimize the following program?

Tags: java, optimization

I want to optimize this program. Currently my program is working slow because functions in the program are very much dependent on other functions in the program. What is the best way to optimize this?

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] testValues = {3, 5, 10};
        for (int i = 0; i < testValues.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(first(testValues[i]));
        }
    }

    public static int first(int a) {
        int b;
        if (a <= 1) {
            if (a == 1) {
                b = convertOne(a);
            } else {
                b = convertTwo(a - 1);
            }
        } else {
            return next(a);
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static int convertOne(int c) {
        return++c;
    }

    public static int convertTwo(int d) {
        int i = 1;
        for (i = d * 11; i > d; i--) {
            i--;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static int next(int e) {
        int container = first(e - 1);
        return container + first(e - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the recursion part you need to convert to a loop? I don't see any.

Comment: @MangoLato `first` call `next`, `next` call `first`.

Comment: while next calling first its taking longer time than normal. So inside next() calling first ()  thats parts need to iterate . I think that would be execution first.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: First of all, recursion is strictly a function that calls itself and has an exit condition. Recursion itself is not a very recommended approach since it is slow and can end provoking stack overflow exception. This being said, you have a circular call. Consider refactoring your code.

Comment: Input : int[] testValues = {3, 5, 10}; Output using recursion : first input 3 and output : 2, Input 5  and output : 5, input 10 and output : 55.

Comment: Is this some kind of joke? This logic is completely fabricated. For example, `if (a == 1) b = convertOne(a)` where `convertOne(a)` returns `a + 1`. So the answer is always 2. The logic as written makes no sense, except as an academic exercise. Vote to close.

Comment: Also `convertTwo` is only called with a negative parameter, in which case the for loop will never execute any iterations. Sorry, this is some kind of practical joke.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, this is some kind of joke or code-golf puzzle. The function is a kind of Fibonacci function with -11 and 2 as the first terms.

The `first` method refactors to:

```
public static int first(int a) {

    if (a <= 0) {
        return (a - 1) * 11;
    }
    if (a == 1) {
        return 2;
    }

    int n0 = -11;
    int n1 = 2;
    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        int t = n0 + n1;
        n0 = n1;
        n1 = t;
    }
    return n1;
}
```

All the rest is junk, or more likely, deliberate obfuscation.

Comment: Yes, it is a puzzle code. But it has taken from real programming old java code drawback situation. I am really confused how can I optimize this situation .

Comment: Well, the code above is fairly optimal. You can investigate optimizing Fibonacci sequences if you want to take it further. But this is not a web-site for programming puzzles. There is a separate site for that: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score -1):

1) One golden rule is; try to avoid **Nesting** as much as possible.

```
if (a <= 1) {
        if (a == 1) {
            b = convertOne(a);
        } else {
            b = convertTwo(a - 1);
        }
    } else {
        return next(a);
    }
```

2) You have used `i--` twice, if its required do it like `i-=2` in a *loop*.

```
public static int convertTwo(int d) {
    int i = 1;
    for (i = d * 11; i > d; i--) {
        i--;
    }
    return i;
}
```

3) Following code is executing inadequate logic.

```
if (a <= 1) {
        if (a == 1) {
            b = convertOne(a);
        } else {
            b = convertTwo(a - 1);
        }// this else is executing for cases < 1, but logic of "convertTwo(a - 1)" is ambiguous, try dry running it for -1 
    } else {
        return next(a);
    }
```

4) Logic of following code also does not need to be in function

```
public static int convertOne(int c) {
    return ++c;
}
```

5) Functions are used to perform single reusable operation. In your `next(int e)` function you are doing nothing *single*. Do this in the *first(int a)* method.

Comment: Its slowing the process when input are big value like : int[] testValues = { 30, 40,100 }. Its taking the maximum time in next method when recursion. I want to convert it recursion to iteration .

Comment: Please have a clear understanding of recursion. You are misunderstanding recursion. Obviously greater values required more iterations that's why its taking time in execution.

Comment: @rghome yes logic needs to be revised. Just listed the common mistakes.